# Customize |<->| arrowhead in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I am quite happy with the `|<->|` arrowhead in Tikz but I would like to control the length of the `|`. Is there a simple way to achieve this? In `tikz.code.tex`, I could find

```
\pgfarrowsdeclarecombine*{tikz@|<@#2}{tikz@>|@#2}{#1}{#2}{|}{|}
```

which is somehow related to the question but it looks like in `pgflibraryarrows.code.tex` there is nothing to grab. It would be nice if this `|` length could be a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much improved answer, thanks to percusse's information that arrowhead parameters can be set (and read) using `\pgfsetarrowoption` (and `\pgfgetarrowoptions`).

The declaration below is adjusted from `pgf`'s declaration of `|`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfarrowsdeclare{var|}{|var}
{
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-0.25\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{+.75\pgflinewidth}
}
{
  \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}
  \pgfsetrectcap
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.25\pgflinewidth}{-\pgfgetarrowoptions{var|}}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.25\pgflinewidth}{\pgfgetarrowoptions{var|}}}
  \pgfusepathqstroke
}

\pgfarrowsdeclarecombine*{var|<}{>|var}{to}{to}{var|}{|var}
\begin{document}
\pgfsetarrowoptions{var|}{10pt}
\tikz{
  \draw[var|-|var] (0,0)--(1,1);
  \draw[var|<->|var] (1,0)--(2,1);
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See the options for the `var arc` example in the manual p.614.

Comment: shoudn't the name of the arrowhead be {|var}{var|}? And the triangles are not possible? What about `var|<->var|`

Comment: yes, I guess `{|var}{var|}` is prettier.  Triangles... you mean the combined arrow? I've included a declaration for `var|<`...`>|var'